# Can I get more than one Death Defiance from Chaos?

Tags: hades

Chaos's Legendary Boon allows you to gain an extra Death Defiance for the duration of the run. I know normally you can't get duplicate boons from gods, but Chaos's boons are very different mechanically and I'm not sure whether they follow the same rules as the other gods.

If I were to reroll enough and get very lucky, could I end up with 2+ extra Chaos-granted Death Defiances on a single run? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You are able to stack this boon additively.

From [the wiki](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Chaos):

> Unlike other boons, you can get the same Blessing more than once in a
> run and the effects stack additively. Their boons cannot be upgraded
> with Pom of Power, or sold.

Additionally, this will give you a permanent +2 (+1 per stack) slot for Death Defiance:

> - This gives Zagreus +1 slot of Defiance, which is only lost after his eventual death
>   Upon depleting, the Defiance slot can be replenished with Kiss of Styx normally

Comment: Here's a screenshot showing 6 death's defiances: https://old.reddit.com/r/HadesTheGame/comments/ej29kg/finally_found_the_legendary_chaos_boon_twice/

Comment: Perfect, thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to know.